# How do I persist cookies after Safari Intelligent Tracking Prevention limits cookies to 1 day, or sandboxes local storage?

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, google-tag-manager

Currently I set first party cookies from Google Tag manager. If cookies live only 1 day, I can recover the cookie if a localstorage variable is available. But my understanding is localstorage is also sandboxed, for anything written by third party tags, to 7 days or so.

How do I persist first party cookies set in GTM?

If first party javascripts can still persist cookies or localstorage variables, probably I would just use the iframe message passing to make the first party javascript set the cookie. Or maybe jsonp. Does anyone know if those work arounds would work, or if my understanding of the sandboxing is correct.